# iTunes Connect error: itc.olympus.partnermessage.lockey.contentprovider.contract.expiresoon.messagebody.app.free

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

[iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) is showing this error:

[image]
itc.olympus.partnermessage.lockey.contentprovider.contract.expiresoon.messagebody.app.free

How do I solve it?

Comment: retry after few hour

Comment: Apple like usual! This is bag no more.

Comment: Are you getting these error after login into itunes or before itself?

Comment: After login , I am getting this error

Comment: @GrigoriJlavyan just go to https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership/ and renew your membership.

Answer (score 3):

**Renew your apple developer account error will be disappear**

I detect it is itune connect bug .. special it bug comming for when itune connect  unalbe to show this massage. 
[image]

usually it is iTune connect bug and  hope apple fix this one as soon as possible 
[image]

note : may it will be safari related problem or itune connect exception throwing

**Summary** you need to Renew  Your Apple Developer Program before Membership Expiration Date from here [Your account on the Apple Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/account/#/overview/RZ43Z4842H)

and you will see this message after login apple developer account 
[image]

further any query talk with apple support 
login iTune connect -> bottom of page -> contact us -> select from drop down -> iTune connect upload and general error help

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Renew your membership to keep your access to Apple Developer Program benefits and services.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say exactly what's the problem.try below things

1. Safari is more suitable for iTunes working process.Try to load with
   other browsers too.
2. clear cache & history of browsers.
3. Update your browsers if you are used with old versions
4. Try with some other system.

if above things are not working, Then it might a bug from iTunes.